# creating automatic relations in drupal

Tags: php, inheritance, drupal

Consider this scenario.

I have 3 nodes A,B,C where A is father of B , B is father of C and I have created these two relations using relations module.
Now it implies that A is grandfather of C. Can we define some rules to handle such cases automatically in drupal, rather than I explicitly defining that A is grandfather of C using relations module.

Comment: you have some advance?

Comment: I think module bundle inherit might not work here but i guess rules modules might work? I have just downloaded and enabled the module as of now.. Let me try to configure it accordingly

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer whats your opinion about rules modules. Bundle Inherit might not work because they are all of the same node type.

Comment: you will have 3 diferents content type, and you can use rules, just make one example and test the module.

Comment: you make the test with bundle inherit?

Comment: you got some advance?

Comment: no havent tried it yet, will try today

Comment: do you make the test?

Comment: i tried it with rules.It worked

Answer (score 1):

Use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/Rules) module. Create a rule which should fire when relation for grandchild created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module [Bundle Inherit](https://www.drupal.org/project/bundle_inherit)

The main target of the Bundle Inherit module is to allow users to inherit bundles of different entity types from any other bundles of the same entity type. Inheritance could be performed while creating new bundle of some entity type (for example new content type). There are two types (modes) of inherit available:

**Soft:** All field instances from existing (parent) bundle will be cloned and attached to the newly created bundle. As for the soft mode it is all.

**Strict:** All field instances from existing (parent) bundle will be cloned and attached to the newly created bundle. After that you will not be able to directly edit inherited field instances in the children bundles and they will be always kept synchronized.